# ~/.bashrc alias to change directory not working

Tags: alias, bash

This is possibly a boring question, but I could not find an answer that I completely understood for the following query.

I moved to a new research institute and I am accessing virtual machines for my research. I want to create a handy bashrc to make life easier.

So, editing the     ~/.bashrc file with the following:

```
alias lhcb = "cd ~/vols/lhcb/bd1316/B2ppKgamma/"
alias work_space = "cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/"
alias Code = "cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/Scripts/"
```

and opening a new terminal to use the updated bashrc file I get the following errors:

```
-bash: alias: alias: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd ~/vols/lhcb/bd1316/B2ppKgamma/: not found
-bash: alias: work_space: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/: not found
-bash: alias: Code: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/Scripts/: not found
```

I do not understand what is going wrong. Could you explain this to me, please, and if possible, provide a fix? Much obliged.

Comment: Please remove spaces around `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash variable declaration does not allow space before and after `=`

```
alias lhcb="cd ~/vols/lhcb/bd1316/B2ppKgamma/"
alias work_space="cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/"
alias Code="cd ~/home/hep/bd1316/Public/Project/Scripts/"
```

Refer [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables/) link.

Comment: Theses aren't variable declarations, but the reason for removing the spaces is essentially the same.

Comment: I know this is old but, how are these not variable declarations?

Comment: @hmcclungiii, it's an alias. Variable declaration is just like this: `STR="Hello World!"`. You can check this site for more information: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html